# ASP.NET MVC, JQUERY Portlets and Personalization

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, portlet, personalization

Is there any sample/links/thoughts for implementing asp.net mvc application with jquery portlets and asp.net personalization provider?
All thoughts/ideas/feedback are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer! just go to http://www.linksgrid.com/ for sample allication, for source code go to http://code.google.com/p/linksgrid/

Comment: This site is unavailable for some reason, and the code repository at google appears to have been cleaned out.  Anyone know if the project has moved to another location?

Comment: hmm links are not accessible right now. *dropthings.com* is another example of such site, have a look at it.